# Lambda string as VARCHAR

Tags: nhibernate, lambda, varchar, string-literals, nvarchar

One of my Join key-selectors looks like this:

```
x => x.A + "-" + x.B
```

NHibernate makes `"-"` an extra parameter. This parameter gets the SQL type `nvarchar` and so the whole statement gets converted on the SQL Server from `varchar` to `nvarchar`.

The problem with this is, that SQL Server has a **huge problem** if the queried column is of type `varchar` instead of `nvarchar`. This is because the column is of another type than the parameter and so the **index can't be used**.

I cannot change the type of the column so I need to define somehow that NHibernate **should use varchar for string literals** when converting lambdas.

Any way to do this?

### UPDATE

With help from Oskar Berggren I setup this classes:

```
public static class VarcharFix
    {
        /// This method returns its argument and is a no-op in C#.
        /// It's presence in a Linq expression sends a message to the NHibernate Linq Provider.
        public static string AsVarchar(string s)
        {
            return s;
        }
    }

public class MyHqlIdent : HqlExpression
    {
        internal MyHqlIdent(IASTFactory factory, string ident)
            : base(HqlSqlWalker.IDENT, ident, factory)
        {
        }

        internal MyHqlIdent(IASTFactory factory, System.Type type)
            : base(HqlSqlWalker.IDENT, "", factory)
        {
            if (IsNullableType(type))
            {
                type = ExtractUnderlyingTypeFromNullable(type);
            }

            switch (System.Type.GetTypeCode(type))
            {
                case TypeCode.Boolean:
                    SetText("bool");
                    break;
                case TypeCode.Int16:
                    SetText("short");
                    break;
                case TypeCode.Int32:
                    SetText("integer");
                    break;
                case TypeCode.Int64:
                    SetText("long");
                    break;
                case TypeCode.Decimal:
                    SetText("decimal");
                    break;
                case TypeCode.Single:
                    SetText("single");
                    break;
                case TypeCode.DateTime:
                    SetText("datetime");
                    break;
                case TypeCode.String:
                    SetText("string");
                    break;
                case TypeCode.Double:
                    SetText("double");
                    break;
                default:
                    if (type == typeof(Guid))
                    {
                        SetText("guid");
                        break;
                    }
                    if (type == typeof(DateTimeOffset))
                    {
                        SetText("datetimeoffset");
                        break;
                    }
                    throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("Don't currently support idents of type {0}", type.Name));
            }
        }

        private static System.Type ExtractUnderlyingTypeFromNullable(System.Type type)
        {
            return type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        }

        // TODO - code duplicated in LinqExtensionMethods
        private static bool IsNullableType(System.Type type)
        {
            return (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>));
        }
    }

    public class MyHqlCast : HqlExpression
    {
        public MyHqlCast(IASTFactory factory, IEnumerable<HqlTreeNode> children)
            : base(HqlSqlWalker.METHOD_CALL, "method", factory, children)
        {

        }

        public static MyHqlCast Create(IASTFactory factory, HqlExpression expression, string targetType)
        {
            return new MyHqlCast(factory,
                                new HqlTreeNode[]
                                {
                                    new MyHqlIdent(factory, "cast"),
                                    new HqlExpressionList(factory, expression,
                                    new MyHqlIdent(factory, targetType))
                                });
        }
    }

    public class MyBaseHqlGeneratorForMethod : BaseHqlGeneratorForMethod
    {
        public MyBaseHqlGeneratorForMethod()
            : base()
        {
            SupportedMethods = new MethodInfo[] { typeof(VarcharFix).GetMethod("AsVarchar") };
        }

        public override HqlTreeNode BuildHql(MethodInfo method, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression targetObject, System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<System.Linq.Expressions.Expression> arguments, HqlTreeBuilder treeBuilder, global::NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.IHqlExpressionVisitor visitor)
        {
            return MyHqlCast.Create(new ASTFactory(new ASTTreeAdaptor()),
                        visitor.Visit(targetObject).AsExpression(),
                        "varchar");
        }
    }

public class ExtendedLinqtoHqlGeneratorsRegistry : DefaultLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry
    {
        public ExtendedLinqtoHqlGeneratorsRegistry()
        {
            this.Merge(new MyBaseHqlGeneratorForMethod());
        }
    }
```

For now it's still not working but I see light ;)

### UPDATE 2: The Query

```
var query = aQueryable
            .Join(bQueryable,
        x => x.AB, x => x.A + VarcharFix.AsVarchar("-") + x.B,
                                (head, middle) => new ...)
```

### UPDATE 3:

As `"-".AsVarchar()` gets **optimized to** `"-"` we need a **dummy parameter**, which cannot be optimized like `"-".AsVarchar(x.A)` - that way the Linq-extension kicks in!

```
var query = aQueryable
            .Join(bQueryable,
        x => x.AB, x => x.A + "-".AsVarchar(x.A) + x.B,
                                (head, middle) => new ...)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "join key-selector"? Can you post an example of the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be multiple ways to do this but here is one:

Invent your own method such as:

```
/// This method returns its argument and is a no-op in C#.
/// It's presence in a Linq expression sends a message to the NHibernate Linq Provider.
public static string AsVarchar(string s)
{
    return s;
}
```

Also create a class to represent the HQL expression fragment:

```
public class MyHqlCast : HqlExpression
{
    private MyHqlCast(IASTFactory factory, IEnumerable<HqlTreeNode> children)
        : base(HqlSqlWalker.METHOD_CALL, "method", factory, children)
    {
    }

    public static MyHqlCast Create(IASTFactory factory, HqlExpression expression,
                                   string targetType)
    {
        return new MyHqlCast(factory,
                             new [] {
                                 new HqlIdent(factory, "cast")),
                                 new HqlExpressionList(factory, expression,
                                         new HqlIdent(factory, targetType)),
                             });
    }
}
```

Then derive a class from BaseHqlGeneratorForMethod. In its constructor, set the SupportedMethods property to the AsVarchar() method. Override the BuildHql() method. It should output the HQL cast constructs equivalent to cast(@param as varchar). Normally you would use the Cast() method on the treeBuilder parameter, but unfortunately this accepts just a System.Type, which isn't good enough for this case. Instead create and return an instance of your MyHqlCast:

```
return MyHqlCast.Create(new ASTFactory(new ASTTreeAdaptor()),
                        visitor.Visit(arguments[0]).AsExpression(),
                        "varchar");
```

Your implementation of BaseHqlGeneratorForMethod then needs to be registered by deriving from DefaultLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry. Call this.Merge(new MyGenerator()); in the constructor. Then register your registry type by

```
nhibernateConfiguration.LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry<MyRegistry>();
```

Comment: First, thank you for your detailed answer! In the 2nd code block you call `AddChild` but as I saw in the NHibernate source it's internal!

Comment: OK, got around the interal thing via another constructor-overload and custom `HqlIdent`. My `MyBaseHqlGeneratorForMethod` constructor gets called via the `LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry` and inside I assign `new MethodInfo[] { typeof(VarcharFix).GetMethod("AsVarchar") }` to SupportedMethods ... but `BuildHql` doesn't get called...

Comment: I've updated my code example. Though I missed that the HqlIdent ctor was also internal.

Comment: Just to make sure, you didn't forget calling Merge()?

Comment: Yes, I do. I've updated the question with my current implementations.

Comment: Do you mean that you've verified with a debugger and breakpoints that the MyBaseHqlGeneratorForMethod ctor is in fact called during configuration, but the BuildHql() is not? Does the MethodInfo array contain non-null values?

Comment: Yes: breakpoint in ctor and BuildHql. Ctor is hit, BuildHql not. In NHProf it says that the parameter is String(4000).

Comment: And MethodInfo-Array count is 1. I even used the built-in `ReflectionHelper.GetMethodDefinition(() => VarcharFix.AsVarchar(""))` helper method.

Comment: In the "did you put the plug in the socket"-section, did you add the call to AsVarchar() in your query?

Comment: Yes ;) - see update 2 in the question. Except the names it's copied from my original query.

Comment: The expression is even evaluated by `PartialEvaluatingExpressionTreeVisitor.EvaluateSubtree()` - I can confirm that `AsVarchar()` function is called by remotion.  To me it seems that extensions are **not meant to extend key-selectors** but ***just*** `Where` expressions because I have another extension flawlessly working

Comment: Interesting... try putting the entire string concatenation inside the call to AsVarchar(). It might be that it evaluates the expression since it doesn't use anything that comes from the database.

Comment: @Warappa Did you try my latest suggestion of putting the entire concatenation expression inside the call to AsVarchar()?

Comment: Yes, I did, but the last time I tried it didn't call BuildHql - *now it does*! (Don't know, I must have something wrong - silly me). `targetObject` is now `null` - I'm just playing around with `arguments` expression list but until now that causes other exceptions...

Comment: Yes, silly of me, targetObject will be null since the method is static.

Comment: OK, if entire lambda is surrounded it gets called - if only string gets surrounded then not. This is because Relinq seems to "reduce" the whole ast so after call of `EvaluateIndependentSubtrees` in `NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.NhPartialEvaluatingExpressionTreeVisitor` the expression `... + "-".AsVarchar() + ...` is reduced to `... + "-" + ...` It seems like AsVarchar() is not allowed to be a noop...

Comment: After adding a "dummy" parameter with cannot be "optimized" (like `x.A`) the varchar-cast works. So the key selector reads `x.A + "-".AsVarchar(x.A) + x.B` - update you answer according to my next update and I accept it. Thanks for keeping on helping!

Comment: All the constructors for HqlIdent are internal. So how can this be done?