# Calling instance methods inside a where conditon in Nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have this piece of code in a TaskRepository :

```
public List<Task> GetActiveTasks()
    {

        return SessionContainer.Session
            .Query<Task>()
            .Where(t => t.IsActive())
            .ToList();
    }
```

And this is the IsActive() method in the Task Class

```
public virtual bool IsActive()                                 
{
 return States.ToList().Max().Name == "Active";
}
```

My problem is that `GetActiveTasks()` returns `NotSupportedException`.

Does anyone knows whats the problem ? I think it is not possible to call instance methods in the Where predicate. If that is not possible, is there any workaround for this? I need to get all the active tasks but I dont know how to do it if it is not like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lambdas given in the Query have to be translated to sql. How should NHibernate interprete a method implemented by you? it can't. However you could map IsActive as a Formula property and query that. Something like:

```
Map(x => x.IsActive).Formula("(SELECT ... FROM (Select s.Name FROM States s WHERE s.task_id = Id ORDER BY Id desc LIMIT 1) maxState WHERE maxState.Name == Active)")
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to refactor the Task class like this:

```
public static Expression<Func<Task, bool>> IsActiveExpr =
    (task) => task.States.Max().Name == "Active";
private static Func<Task, bool> _IsActiveCompiled = IsActiveExpr.Compile();

public virtual bool IsActive()                                 
{
    return IsActiveCompiled(this);
}
```

Now you can use IsActiveExpr in LINQ queries.

Another options is to extend the NHibernate query provider so that it recognizes the IsActive() method directly. Do a search, or see for instance my reply to this question: [Lambda string as VARCHAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396166/lambda-string-as-varchar/14399760). But care might need to be taken to avoid duplicating logic.